# Reassigning Colour from Integer Value (args)

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, colors

Hi I have managed to store the colour into a database table as an arg type integer. But now I am not sure how I turn that back into a colour so I can use it.

```
mCatButList[i].BackColour = Color.FromArgb((int)CatRow[8]);
```

Tried this and I am just getting grey. When the value in `CatRow[8]` is `8421631`.

Comment: what color u expect by  this  value 8421631?

Comment: A teal (green/blue) type colour. `255, 247, 217`

Comment: How did you turn the Color into an int?

Comment: `.BackColor.ToArgb();`to an int varable

Comment: sorry i added the extra tag... winforms

Comment: If there is another way to send a colour to a database then retrieve and use the value I am all ears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BackColor = Color.FromArgb(147, 230, 203); // which is  the teal color
```

and then you convert it to  int

```
int backColor = BackColor.ToArgb();
```

you will  get a signed value like this `-7084341  // which is a negative number`

last try to be sure that your database accept a signed integer

Comment: .. value should have been '-7084341' in the database... doh! was a positive number in there.. Been a long day.. but thanks for responding ill give you the answer for getting me to look in my database ha!